# gem require error: file to import not found

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a project using sass and i have a config.rb file setup to 'require' a gem ([zen grids](http://zengrids.com/)) which is then '@import'ed in my main `.scss` file but i'm getting errors `File to import not found or unreadable: zen` when I try to compile.

I'm running Mac OSX 10.8.3 and am using RVM and have 1.9.3-p362 as my default version.

Can anybody help? I would really appreciate any feedback on this.

Comment: which ruby gem are you using for this? give me github link.
have you mentioned that gem in Gemfile?

Comment: I'm trying to get sass/compass to import [zen-grids](https://github.com/JohnAlbin/zen-grids).

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this. I think it was my structure. I let compass create a project for me and then I simply imported all the requires and @imports which I needed. No more errors and it all compiles fine.